# Xively datastreams PNG server error

Tags: xively

I want to display on my website my data in graph format using this, but it gives a Xively server error after a while.

https://api.xively.com/v2/feeds/1212121212/datastreams/countingsheep.png

I can see other formats such as JSON but not PNG.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `?duration=6hours&interval=0` to the end of your URL. It appears that there is no default for these parameters, resulting in Xively calling your request "bad". Adjust those parameters to suit your needs.